# trying to defuse Binary Bomb phase 5 (phase_5)

Tags: linux, binary, gdb, buffer, disassembly

This seems like a very popular question but i've been looking at this for a few hours now, and i just cant seem to decode it. I do know I need a lookup table and to somehow create a six digit string that is equivalent 0x34, also each character from my input string is ANDed with 0xf, and the result is used to get the character with the corresponding index from the array. Just cant seem to find 6 suitable characters to defuse the bomb.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
=> 0x08048dd5 <+0>: push   %ebx
   0x08048dd6 <+1>: sub    $0x14,%esp
   0x08048dd9 <+4>: mov    0x1c(%esp),%ebx
   0x08048ddd <+8>: push   %ebx
   0x08048dde <+9>: call   0x8049043 <string_length>
   0x08048de3 <+14>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048de6 <+17>:    cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048de9 <+20>:    je     0x8048df0 <phase_5+27>
   0x08048deb <+22>:    call   0x8049159 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048df0 <+27>:    mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x08048df2 <+29>:    add    $0x6,%ebx
   0x08048df5 <+32>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x08048dfa <+37>:    movzbl (%eax),%edx
   0x08048dfd <+40>:    and    $0xf,%edx
   0x08048e00 <+43>:    add    0x804a100(,%edx,4),%ecx
   0x08048e07 <+50>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048e0a <+53>:    cmp    %ebx,%eax
   0x08048e0c <+55>:    jne    0x8048dfa <phase_5+37>
   0x08048e0e <+57>:    cmp    $0x34,%ecx
   0x08048e11 <+60>:    je     0x8048e18 <phase_5+67>
   0x08048e13 <+62>:    call   0x8049159 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e18 <+67>:    add    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048e1b <+70>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048e1c <+71>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) 
(gdb) x/16dw 0x804a100
0x804a100 <array.3248>: 2   10  6   1
0x804a110 <array.3248+16>:  12  16  9   3
0x804a120 <array.3248+32>:  4   7   14  5
0x804a130 <array.3248+48>:  11  8   15  13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i needed to create a six character string that is equivalent 0x34 which is 52.
i used abcdef, ghijkl, mnopqr as test strings while using (gdb) info r to observe the changes in register ecx for each different character while the program was looping eg. a ->10, b ->6...
so as to save time i created a breakpoint at  0x08048e07.
then i use 6 characters summing up to 52.
eg. of solutions are:
dmmmmm,
mmmmmd

```
a=10 10
b=16 6
c=17 1 
d=29 12
e=45 16
f=54 9

g=3  3
h=7  4
i=14 7
j=28 21
k=33 5
l=44 11

m=8   8
n=23  15
o=36  13
p=38  3
q=48  10
r=54  6
```